# Get Current Product Information in Controller Magento 2?

Tags: php, magento, controller

I want to get the current product information in a controller.

I created a function in block, and called that function in my phtml file.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Before continuing, could you please spend a minute and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

With reference from this article - https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/alternatives-for-deprecated-registry-class-magento-2-3/

You can:

1. Add \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session into the contructor of your controller so that it can instantiate the catalog session object:

```
    public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            \Magento\Catalog\ModelSession $catalogSession
           ) {
            $this->catalogSession = $catalogSession;
            parent::__construct($context);
           }
```

2. In the execute method of the controller to get the ProductId use:

```
    $productId = $this->catalogSession->getData('last_viewed_product_id');
```

3. With Product Id, you can load the product data:

```
    $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get product detail through controller you can refer to following links :

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-current-category-current-product/
https://www.mageplaza.com/how-get-current-product-category-magento-2.html

Comment: i want to get product detail from block to controller